# How to ignore ContextRefreshedEvent when SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I'm struggling to find out how to ignore a class method, which should start a thread when SpringBootApplication is ready, during normal operation:

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    this.start();
}
```

in case of testing I do not want such behavior, want to start it from test method.
As far as i understand `ContextRefreshedEvent` is triggered by `@SpringBootTest` annotation on test class.

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution for above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For testing the listener itself:

You do not need `@SpringBootTest` for every test of Spring Boot application (I would argue that you want minimum of such tests actually as they load everything.)

There are other options:

- If you don't need anything from Spring: Unit test the service with Mockito (if it has dependencies you want to mock away).
- Otherwise: Use slices - for example [`@JsonTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-json-tests) will autoconfigure `ObjectMapper` and other beans for working with JSON. There's quite a few of them so check documentation if there's any part of application you would like to be autoconfigured for your test.

### For excluding the listener from other `@SpringBootTest` tests:

I see two options:

- Mocking the listener bean away using `@MockBeans`.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@MockBeans(@MockBean(Listener.class))
public class SomeTest {
  // ...
}
```

- Executing tests inside a specific profile and mark the listener bean to be included only inside the default profile. (Or not inside the "test" profile.)

```java
@Component
@Profile("default") // OR: @Profile("!test")
public class Listener {
  // ...
}

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeTest {
  // ...
}
```

You might need to extract the listener from the existing bean if you need the bean as a dependency for another service though.